# Do leg braces help with older dog ACL tears?

Tags: dogs, injury, senior-pet

I have a fourteen-year-old Weimaraner. He's mentally doing very well and still loves to play.  He recently stopped using one of his legs. He had been slightly limping on it for a while, but one day he stopped using it all together.

Because of his advanced age, surgery isn't an option for us.  He spends most of his days laying down now, and I can tell it hurts when he walks around.

We aren't 100% sure it's an ACL tear, but that was our vets best guess *(other than something untreatable like bone cancer)*.

Has anyone had any experience putting leg braces on dogs for ACL tears?

Comment: Is he on any pain medicine?

Comment: Yes, he was put on two different types of pain meds and an anti-inflammatory medication.  I don't have them with me to give the names, but he continues to limp in the same way on pain meds (He's been on them for about 4 days now)

Comment: It turned out to be bone cancer, and one of his legs was probably fractured from bone weakness associated with bone cancer.  He's no longer in pain.